# Wait-Job doesn't wait

Tags: powershell, wait

Here is code

```
try{
    $SetupJob = invoke-command -ComputerName $j -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock $sb -AsJob | Out-Null

}
catch [System.Exception]{
    continue
}

$SetupJob|Wait-Job


$disable_command = "D:\PSTools\PsExec.exe $comp -u Administrator -p $str -accepteula powershell.exe c:\share\ps_disable.ps1"
$CmdOutput = Invoke-Expression $disable_command 2>&1



Remove-Item Z:\ps_*able.ps1
Remove-Item Z:\setup.exe
```

`$SetupJob` executes `setup.exe` on a remote_computer. After execution, it is supposed to be removed. But, I get the following

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item \\remote_computer\share\setup.exe: The process cannot access the file '\\remote_computer\share\setup.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pipe the output of Invoke-Command to Out-Null. If you do then `$SetupJob` is going to be null and Wait-Job will return immediately.

Comment: this works, but it outputs to the Powershell ISE console. How to suppress this?

Comment: @Glowie I think you want to pipe the output of Wait-Job to Out-Null, not the output of Invoke-Command.